# differential_drive compilation error: request for member ‘__getMD5Sum’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’

Tags: ros, differential-drive

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/differential_drive

but when I compile it I get the following error:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value(const M&) [with M = int]’:
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_traits.h:255:104:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::md5sum(const M&) [with M = int]’
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = int]’
  /home/d4n/sdc2130/src/auto.cpp:204:29:   instantiated from here
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_traits.h:126:34: error: request for member ‘__getMD5Sum’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType<M>::value(const M&) [with M = int]’:
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_traits.h:264:106:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::datatype(const M&) [with M = int]’
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = int]’
  /home/d4n/sdc2130/src/auto.cpp:204:29:   instantiated from here
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_traits.h:143:36: error: request for member ‘__getDataType’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value(const M&) [with M = int]’:
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_traits.h:127:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType<M>::value(const M&) [with M = int]’:
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_traits.h:144:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sdc2130.dir/src/auto.cpp.o] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sdc2130.dir/all] Error 2
```

the line that give me the error is:

```
rwheel_pub.publish(absenc2);
```

someone tell that could be an error from the different format type of the variable, could someone help me a little more?

thanks guys

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69574/differential_drive-compilation-error:-request-for-member-%E2%80%98__getmd5sum%E2%80%99-in-%E2%80%98m%E2%80%99,-which-is-of-non-class-type-%E2%80%98const-int%E2%80%99/) by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is absenc2 an **int** or an **std_msgs::Int8**. It should be the latter

---

Originally posted by [Michael.Camilleri](https://answers.ros.org/users/8126/michael.camilleri/) with karma: 26 on 2013-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aymar111](https://answers.ros.org/users/27718/aymar111/) on 2017-01-04**:
a more detailled answer :

```
std_msgs::Int8 absenc2;
absenc2.data=0;
rwheel_pub.publish(absenc2);
```

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-03-23**:
I find on some systems I can compile `int val=8;  pub.publish(val)` and other times I can't and get the md5sum error and have to make the message and assign the value to data, as if different compile options are being used in either case.